# Combine Arcore with google VR

Tags: android, opengl-es, virtual-reality, arcore

I'm trying to run Arcore in cardboard headset. I'm thinking about rendering [ARcore view to rectangle](http://www.felixjones.co.uk/neo%20website/Android_View/) and then use GoogleVR to render it in VR. Is there any better way to do it?